# Is it possible to group rows this way using MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table like:

```
ID, USER, PARAM, VAL
--------------------
1 | 1 | NAME | ADAM
2 | 1 | AGE  | 15
3 | 2 | NAME | EVA
4 | 2 | AGE  | 16
5 | 3 | NAME | CRISS
6 | 3 | AGE  | 14
```

And I'm curious if there is a query which would give me something similar to:

```
1 | ADAM | 15
2 | EVE  | 16
3 | CRISS| 14
```

So far I'm just using the below query and grouping the records in a loop.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE PARAM ='NAME' OR PARAM = 'AGE'
```

I tried to use `GROUP` but without success.

Comment: Why did you structure the table like that?

Comment: Why not make a table with: id, user, name, age

Comment: Because each user have different parameters - about 20 and that value can be easily changed in the future. This way is much easier to add something without ALTERing table. I just need tu get NAMEs and AGEs throught one query.

Comment: That's an abomination. Seriously.

Comment: @SBI fairly common - see [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

Comment: @BoristheSpider Oh I'm fully aware of that. Doesn't change my opinion on it though. Doesn't make it better just because people are using it. It's the complete misuse of what a relational database gives you in terms of optimizations, concise queries etc. Which is precisely why many databases try to avoid / circumvent it (sparse columns in mssql, postgres with xpath subqueries).

Comment: @SBI agree - pushing schema-less data onto a SQL database is indeed a rather ugly thing to do. The fact remains though, that lots of data is schema-less, at least to some extent, and lots of data is stored in SQL. Having multiple datastores is often Not An Option (TM).

Comment: @BoristheSpider Totally agree, and my edit was a bit late, because even if you have to go through with it (after putting up one hell of a struggle of course), there are at least a hand full of feasibly alternatives. While not great, they can take away some of the pain.

Comment: Impossible! Your data has "Eva" and you want "Eve". We're not miracle workers :-)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `SELECT 'Eve' WHERE VAL = 'Eva'`; yey miracles...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Good job :)

Comment: Why did EVA suddenly become EVE ?

Comment: Be cautious with this sort of approach towards databases. This comes very close to violating the [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) (1NF) property of relational database.

Comment: @gkubed yes, but this query is just for generation of monthly reports :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do a query like that:

```
SELECT t1.user,
        (
           SELECT val FROM tab1 t2 
           WHERE t2.user = t1.user 
             AND t2.param = 'Name'
        ) name,
        (
           SELECT val FROM tab1 t2 
           WHERE t2.user = t1.user 
             AND t2.param = 'Age'
        ) age
    FROM tab1 t1
    GROUP BY user
```

Another possibility is group_concat, but then you have all values listen in one columns.

```
SELECT user, group_concat(param, ':', val)
    FROM tab1
    GROUP BY user
```

Answer (score 15):

Use join on the same table:

```sql
SELECT a.USER user_id, a.VAL user_name, b.VAL user_age
FROM `table` a
INNER JOIN `table` b ON a.USER = b.USER
WHERE a.PARAM = 'NAME'
AND b.PARAM = 'AGE'
```

Result:

```
user_id     user_name   user_age
1           ADAM        15
2           EVA         16
3           CRISS       14
```

Comment: This is a better approach compared to max/group by.

Comment: @SalmanA why? AFAIK it's worse. Try using it with more than 1 or 2 values to get, you need a join for each new column.

Answer (score 9):

There's no need to use JOIN.  Try this:

```
SELECT USER,
       MAX(CASE PARAM WHEN 'NAME' THEN VAL ELSE NULL END) AS NAME,
       MAX(CASE PARAM WHEN 'AGE' THEN VAL ELSE 0 END) AS AGE
FROM test 
GROUP BY USER;
```

Comment: This is efficient and I have used it sometimes, for example in data transformation for ETL. You can make it shorter and more readable removing the `ELSE NULL` (and thinking about readable, add some newlines)

Comment: I've used both style of query to solve this problem and I can say that this one is both faster and, in my opinion, more readable, especially when you have lots of user attributes to check.

Comment: The `ELSE NULL` is useless, but the `ELSE 0` could be plainly wrong in some cases. Now voting for @Abhik Chakraborty

Answer (score 8):

You can generate the pivot view by using the most commonly used technique as

```
select
user,
max(case when param = 'NAME' then val end) as name,
max(case when param = 'AGE' then val end) as age
from mytable
group by user
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi i replicate your problem in my db example, try this query:

```
    SELECT t1.USER,VAL,(SELECT VAL AS AGE FROM table1 where USER = t1.USER AND PARAM = 'AGE') as AGE 
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE param = 'NAME'
```

or use join on your table:

```
SELECT a.USER, a.VAL, b.VAL
FROM table1  t1
INNER JOIN table1 t2 
ON t1.USER = t2.USER
WHERE t1.PARAM = 'NAME'
AND t2.PARAM = 'AGE'
```

**replace table1 with your table name.**